# how to create a list about my tables from sql server?

Tags: list, ssms, database-table

I have a lot of tables in my database (Microsoft Sql Server), and I want to create some kind of list, about my tables. I don't want to write all of the tables' names, I thought there is a way, to create a list about the names of the tables in Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio. Maybe a query which gives me the table names? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   DATABASENAME.SYS.TABLES 
ORDER  BY NAME
```